# SQL Server - converting date to D-MMM-YYYY format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date-formatting

How can I get the string from `GETDATE()` in `D-MMM-YYYY` format, e.g `3 May 2016`

If I use `CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 106)`, I would get a leading zero on day which is not what I want.

Comment: Format it at your front-end client where the data is being shown. Don't do it in SQL end

Comment: Carefully consider _why_ you are trying to format a date in a database. It's almost always a bad idea or a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 6):

If you are on SQL Server 2012 or later, use `FORMAT`:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'd MMM yyyy')
```

**Edit:** some of the answers below are just flat-out wrong so I'm adding a solution for older versions of SQL Server. 2005 is the earliest that I can get my hands on:

```
SELECT CASE
        WHEN CONVERT(varchar(20), GETDATE(), 106) LIKE '0%'
            THEN SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(20), GETDATE(), 106), 2, 20)
        ELSE CONVERT(varchar(20), GETDATE(), 106)
       END
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT case when left(convert(varchar(20),[DateColumn],106),1) ='0'
       then right(convert(varchar(20),[DateColumn],106),len(convert(varchar(20),[DateColumn],106))-1)
       else convert(varchar(20),[DateColumn],106)
       end
  FROM [DB].[dbo].[Table]
```

Some sample output :

```
29 Apr 2016
2 Apr 2016
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use `FORMAT` (Below SQL Server 2012)

```
DECLARE @date DATE = '20160503'

SELECT REPLACE(DATEPART(DAY, @date),' 0','') + ' ' +
       CONVERT(CHAR(3), @date, 0) + ' ' +
       CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, @date) AS CHAR(4))
```

Comment: Your solution will convert `30 May 2016` to `3 May 2016`. Also there's no guarantee that `CAST(GETDATE() AS CHAR(3)) ` will give you the month name. Try replacing `GETDATE()` with a `date` (not `datetime`) variable

Comment: @CodeDifferent Updated the answer. You can also try it with `20160530`